# If else statement comparing to 0 or NA

Tags: r, if-statement

I have an element in a data frame tmp that may contain either a number, 0, or NA. If that element is neither 0 or NA, I would like something to happen. Otherwise, nothing happens. I imagine it'd look like this:

```
  if ( tmp[2, 19] != (0 || NA) ){  
              do something
              }
```

I get this error: Error in if (tmp[2, 19] == (0 || NA)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed. I don't know if it's not possible in R to compare something to both an int and a string or if I'm just using the OR operator wrong. I've tried different variations in different cases but haven't been able to determine the problem. Please help!

Answer (score 6):

As @GSee said in a comment, you need to use `is.na`:

```
if(tmp[2, 19] != 0 || is.na(tmp[2, 19])) {  
  # do stuff
}
```

You could have discovered this yourself by reading `?"if"` and `?NA`.